# How to open file from keybindings.json without extensions in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are some complex commands that can be invoked with `args`:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+w",
    "command": "vscode.setEditorLayout",
    "args": {
        "orientation": 0,
        "groups": [
            {
                "groups": [
                    {},
                    {}
                ],
                "size": 0.7
            },
            {
                "groups": [
                    {},
                    {}
                ],
                "size": 0.3
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

`vscode.open` appears in `command` autocomplete and therefore should be able to work. But I cannot find what to pass as `args` for it to work.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands

P.S. I know I can use extensions. Just looking if it's possible or not.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with vscode.open as a snippet.  In the path key, it doesn't show a last single-escape as an error: some\\path\test.js  That last escape, not being two escapes should be an error - it is not flagged as such on my machine.  But the same in vscode.openFolder does trigger the error squiggly.  So that is quiet strange.